# mousemove don't fire every frame when a keyboard event is fired

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousemove

Ideally in a browser, `mousemove` should fire every frame when the mouse keeps moving. But when a key is pressed (or repeated) or released, the `mousemove` stops firing for a frame or two.
We can test this with the following code:

```js
t0 = new Date().getTime()
window.onmousemove = function() {
    t = new Date().getTime()
    if (t-t0 > 20)
        console.log(t-t0)
    t0 = t
}
```

Try keep your mouse moving. The console will print delay of `mousemove` only when you press, release a key or keep a key pressed (because it's repeated).

I have tested this on both Firefox and Chrome. I use macOS 10.14.2.

I'm writing a web action game, so I need to make sure the mouse position is updated every frame. Any solutions please?

Comment: Having checked this in Chrome, I see that there are many cases where `t-t0` is logged. Remember that JS has a single loop and many things may cause some kind of delay. Try it on this page and hover over the tags in your question. This will also cause a log.

Comment: that's right @JamieDixon ,   a lot of calls happening those also take time

Answer (score 0):

```
t0 = new Date().getTime()
window.onmousemove = function() {
    t = new Date().getTime()
    if (t-t0 > 2)
        console.log(t-t0)
    t0 = t
}
```

this will make console.log() go crazy fast it wil not skip when you move your mouse fast  ,  also  tested your  code  doesn't skip when pressing   keys    ,     on Chrome , Windows10

also you should consider  using   a main loop for your game  to handle and manage times  and frames  and  events